# The img src moves when zoomed

Tags: html, css

hi guys the image src moves when i zoom the page. . .when viewing with firefox the image is aligned differently in my lap and pc. . .already i have div in it

```
<div class="offer" style="position:absolute">
<img src="images/offer2.png" alt="" width="70" height="70" border="0" style="position:absolute; left:520px; top:325px; width: 70px; height: 70px;" />
<a style=" color:#000000; position:absolute; left:505px; top:340px; width: 102px; height: 82px; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; " Title="Offer Price"  > 10%<br>OFF </a>
</div>
```

Comment: try putting it on a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and explain how you want it to behave, and how it differs from how it is really behaving.

Comment: I can't figure out the solution, but I noticed that you have invalid html code.  I'd recommend removing the quote right after **font-weight:bold** . It may help you find the solution.

Comment: You also say you already have a div in it, yet there's no mention of that in the code you supplied. Be sure to include all code relevant to the problem.

Comment: Waffle i removed the quote, thanks

Comment: Dave I have posted it too. Please see it

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between device (physical) and css pixels.
When the user zooms in, the element with a specified width takes up more and more of the screen. This way it becomes wider, when it is measured in physical pixels, but it has the same size in css pixels. 
This also happens to the space that you left on the top and the left side of the element. That is why it looks like to you, that the element is moving.